# Chrome extension - get data from received responses

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest, google-chrome

Is there any possibility to live tracking all responses in a web browser and getting the data as from the developer tools? (but automatically, not manually)

Example:

- show network in developer tools
- load site [jsonapi.org/examples](https://jsonapi.org/examples/)
- as you can see, there is a JSON file (manifest.json)
  [image: network]
- I can get the JSON (copy it or declare a variable in the console), but there is my question: is it possible to get such a file automatically by an extension?

If so, how can I achieve it? What libraries to use?